# Remove multiple data from firebase

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I uses a wrap of kreait/firebase-php for processing needed requests. I need to realize removing old data, but them too much for removing data one by one entry. How I can to remove multiple data by one request?
this is an example of my current code:

```
$keys = [..keys of data ..];
foreach ($keys as $key) {
   $firebase->getReference(<collection> . '/' . $key)->remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about Firebase's Realtime Database, you can send a [multi-path update request](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/realtime-database.html#update-specific-fields) with the values for each key set to `null` to remove a lot of nodes in one go.